# Unable to click on an element using codeceptjs

Tags: click, mouseclick-event, withings, execute-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5abCE.png)I have tried below approaches to click on an element but unable to click and always click in the background of the page:-

Using css:

```
submitButtonEnabled: { css: 'button.button--enabled[type="submit"]' },
I.click(this.submitButtonEnabled);
```

Also tried xpath.
and

```
I.click('Submit',this.submitButtonEnabled); or I.click("Submit");
```

Also tried within keyword like :

```
within({css:'div.scrollable.panel__scrollable'},()=>{
      I.click('Submit',this.submitButtonEnabled);

});
```

Notes: Its working fine if browser size is not maximized.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same situation. I used to use xpath this way:

```
I.click('//button[@type="submit"]');
```